# Derivative of complex expression

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, proof-verification, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have the following expression
$$f(z)=Q +zS+\bar{z}S^\top + \bar{z}Rz$$
with $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $Q,S,R$ are real matrices of suitable dimensions and $Q=Q^\top$, $R=R^\top$.  I want to show that the above expression is convex, therefore I computed the double derivative with respect to $z$ to see if it is $>0$, but I'm not sure whether my derivative is correct or not. I computed
$$f'(z)=S+S^\top + Rz+\bar{z}R$$
Is this correct? In particular, I am not sure about the derivative of $\bar{z}S^\top + \bar{z}Rz$